# ¿Cómo seleccionar la fila donde se encuentra un botón en un TableView javafx?

Tags: javafx

Un Cordial saludo soy nuevo en javafx y estoy aprendiendo a utilizar el TableView, el asunto es el siguiente, muestro los datos de una tabla en un TableView, por cada fila obtenida le coloco un botón Modificar, con la intención que al pulsar el botón me cargue otra ventana donde pueda editar los valores de la fila seleccionada. Si hago click en una celda del TableView y luego presiono el botón modificar puedo obtener los valores de la fila seleccionada. El problema surge cuando doy click al botón sin seleccionar una celda, y es allí donde necesito su ayuda. Necesito obtener los datos de la fila donde se encuentra el botón sin seleccionar una celda. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public void  setBtnModificar(TableView<UsuarioAdministrador> tablaMostrar){
  btnModificar = new Button("Modificar");
  btnModificar.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) ->{
  List<UsuarioAdministrador> filaSeleccionada =  tablaMostrar.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
  if (filaSeleccionada.size() == 1) {
            final UsuarioAdministrador competicionSeleccionada = filaSeleccionada.get(0);
            System.out.println("Valor: "+competicionSeleccionada.getIdAdministrador());
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Una opción puede ser incluir el botón como una propiedad de la clase `UsuarioAdministrador`, y entonces puedes determinar fácilmente la instancia seleccionada.

```
public class UsuarioAdministrador {

    private StringProperty id;
    private ObjectProperty<Button> boton;

    public UsuarioAdministrador(String id) {

        this.id = new SimpleStringProperty(id);
        this.boton = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Button("Modificar"));

        this.boton.get().setOnAction((event) -> {
            // Aqui puedes seleccionar la instancia de usuario que corresponde y cargar la nueva ventana
            UsuarioAdministrador usuarioSeleccionado = this;
        });

    }

    // Getters y Setters
}
```

Después de modificar los valores en otra ventana es posible que tengas que recargar la tabla para que aparezcan los valores actualizados, puedes hacerlo con .

```
tablaMostrar.refresh();
```

Comment: Realice los cambios que indicaste y quedo perfecto. Mil gracias!!